# Jquery calendar overlapped by flash

Tags: jquery, flash, calendar, overlap

I use a jquery calendar and a flash in the same page.. What happens is my jquery calendar is overlapped by my flash... Any suggestion to make it display above flash...
[image]

Look at the image and see my calendar Fr,sat are invisible because of flash...

**EDIT:**
This is what i used,

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="702" height="443">
      <param name="movie" value="images/homebanner.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
      <embed src="images/homebanner.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="702" height="443" wmode="transparent"></embed>
    </object>
```

Comment: Are you sure the z-index of the calendar is greater than that of the Flash?

Comment: What was the solution to your problem?  You seem to have marked an answer as accepted but it's not clear that it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When embedding the flash, use wmode=transparent or opaque. If it's still not working, mess around a bit with the z-index of the different elements.

Comment: Give the calendar a z-index of 50, and see what happens. Does it show the same behaviour in all major browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Use wmode='opaque' on the flash object and embed tags, that should fix it.

It's a param tag under , i.e. `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` and just an attribute on the  tag, i.e. `wmode='opaque'`

Comment: @Lazarus I did that but that didn't help

Comment: @Pandiya, that's odd... I've used this fix a number of times. Try @Jasper's suggestion and shift the z-index of the flash element. Have you tried the 'transparent' option on wmode?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this isn't possible. Flash isn't rendered as a part of the page - a placeholder is made, the page is rendered around the placeholder, and then the Flash is slapped over the top after the rendering has been done.

Maybe it'll be different in Chrome once Flash is built in (as announced recently), but that'll be of limited help if the other browsers don't do it, and is no use to anyone in the here and now.